# How can I get at runtime the type of a wildcard upper bound?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, guava, type-erasure

Suppose I am keeping a registry of subclasses of a certain class, `T`:

```
public class ClassRegistry<T> {
    Set<Class<? extends T>> klasses;
    ...
    public void register(Class<? extends T> klass) {
        klasses.add(klass);
    }
```

You register yourself with a call like `registry.register(this.getClass())`.  I would like to make this simpler with a method on `ClassRegistry<T>` where you just pass yourself, `this`, e.g., `registry.register(this)`:

```
    public void register(Object obj) {
        Class<?> klass = obj.getClass();
        this.register(klass);
    }
```

Oops, this is wrong, because it calls itself (matching the overload with parameter type `Object` and not, of course, `Class<? extends T>`).  So, instead:

```
    public void register(Object obj) {
        Class<? extends T> klass = obj.getClass();
        this.register(klass);
    }
```

And now of course that doesn't compile because the compiler doesn't know that your `obj` is actually of some type `? extends T`.  And it might not, at that, because the caller might be wrong.

So my question is:  How do I test/validate that `obj` is a subclass of `T` which is a wildcard upper bound (so I can safely cast)?  (I suspect - or maybe, hope - the answer involves Guava's [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html#TypeToken(java.lang.Class)), which is why I added the Guava tag, but I'll take any answer, thanks!)

Comment: Why does `register` accept an `Object` instead of a `T`?

Comment: fun thought - what if `T=Class` ? :)

Comment: @LouisWasserman - uh, because of a brain fart?  Anyway, ignore that for the sake of knowing: I'd still like to find out how it's done because I might have some other reason to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be able to register any object of any type, which is what the type `Object` means on your `register` method.

I would change the type of that parameter to `T`.  Then, you can guarantee that `obj.getClass()` will return a `Class<? extends T>`.  The compiler won't quite agree to that, because the [Javadocs for `getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) state:

> **The actual result type is Class where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called.**

The result of the call to `getClass()` is not `Class<? extends T>`, but `Class<? extends Object>` (the erasure of `T`).  You can cast it to `Class<? extends T>`, and that will generate an unchecked cast warning.  However, because you now `obj` is a `T`, I think that type safety is preserved.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void register(T obj) {
    Class<? extends T> klass = (Class<? extends T>) obj.getClass();
    this.register(klass);
}
```

Comment: or just do it raw - `Class klass = obj.getClass();`

Comment: Yeah, as I just answered to @LouisWasserman above, I blew this simple question due to ... um, it being right before lunch or something.  Your answer is the correct way for me to write the `register` method - but I'd still like to know how to get the upper bound's type...

Comment: @davidbak, the answer is pretty much that you can't because of erasure.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Ah.  I thought there might be some kind of mild trick like you use to get the actual type via a `TypeToken`, but slightly different.  But now that I think of what you're saying, it's really gone, isn't it?  Not even reflection will help you. Oh well.